# Change the separator of the Solr synonyms list

Tags: solr, config, synonym

My list of synonyms, extracted from a thesaurus, contains commas, generally used to put the main word in the first place, for example for person names or geographic names:

```
Barack Obama => Obama, Barack
```

But the list of synonyms of Solr uses only the "," as separator. So I need to change it to something like "|" or to add an enclosure. Where are these options?

Comment: So the question is: how to add a synonym that contains a ","?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the comma? `Obama\, Barack`

Comment: Indeed, it does the trick! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a backslash - `\` - to escape special characters in the `synonyms.txt` file:

```
Barack Obama => Obama\, Barack
```